# php reads mysql id shows 01 02 03

Tags: php

I wanna php output my mysql 1 as 01, 2 as 02.... and so on,
so I get database ID first then I wrote this code for output

```
if ($id <10) {
    echo '0'.$id;
} else {
    echo $id;
}
```

and then I want to insert $id to my class then in a loop

```
 while ($sth <100) {
     $id = mysql_result($result,$mtt,"ID");
     echo "<div class='active_$id'>$info</div>";

  $sth++
}
```

how should i replace

```
if ($id <10) {
    echo '0'.$id;
} else {
    echo $id;
}
```

to `$id`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should write:

```
$id = str_pad($id, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [str_pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php), or [printf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php).

```
str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); // works
printf("%02d", $i); // works too
```